# why don't I get the value from an Object.key via javascript

Tags: javascript

In my unit test, I get an `Object` and I can list the keys.
However, I can't get the value for a specific key:

```
wrapper = mount(Toolbar, { router, i18n });
const currentFlag= wrapper.find("#current-flag")
const currentFlagObject = currentFlag.attributes("src")
console.log(Object.keys(currentFlagObject))
console.log(currentFlagObject['src'])
```

console:

```
console.log tests/unit/Toolbar.spec.js:27
  [ 'id', 'src', 'width' ]
console.log tests/unit/Toolbar.spec.js:28
  [object Object]
```

Why can't i get the key value?

Comment: try console.log(currentFlagObject.src);

Comment: thanks but it does not work as the object is a JS object not a JSON one

Comment: JSON.stringify(currentFlagObject.src)

Comment: @JasminMistry  `currentFlagObject.src` and `currentFlagObject['src']` are equivalent. There must not be a different result for both of them.

Comment: It seems a little bit tricky ...  using JSON.stringify(currentFlagObject).src is given me another JS object . ( it's a file... and not a path string...)

Comment: `JSON.stringify(currentFlagObject).src`  shouldn't work at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

This will print the stringify version of object. So instead of `[object Object]` as an output you will get the content of object.

in your case it will be

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(currentFlagObject['src']))
```

Comment: yes thanks ... and I discover that the src is anobject too....  a flag file.... not the path...

Answer (score 0):

Try DOM getAttribute() Method

```
 currentFlag.getAttribute("src");
```